# Do fishing/ do some fishing

Tags: grammar

> 1. You want to do fishing?
> 2. Do you know how to do fishing?

Are both correct with the word fishing standing alone, or should there be "some" all the time?

Comment: Did you search on "do fishing" to see what kind of examples there are? You should add some.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I feel like "do fishing" sounds weird. I would expect _you want to go fishing?_ or _do you know how to fish?_ Also, I would expect _you want to do **some** fishing?_ Maybe it's a regional thing.

Comment: @max, you are right. **do fishing** is weird. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=go+fishing%2Cdo+fishing%2Cdo+some+fishing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgo%20fishing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20fishing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20some%20fishing%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2):

As a native English speaker, I would never say "do fishing."

I would say:

> 1. Do you want to go fishing?
> 2. Do you know how to fish?

The word "some" is unnecessary.

The only context in which I could see myself using "some" in this sense, might be:

> Friend: "What do you want to do today?"
>
> Me: "How about some fishing?"

But even then, the word "some" is not necessary. I could still say "How about fishing?" and retain the same meaning.

The word "some" would only be significant if you were using it to emphasize quantity or degree.

Example:

> child: "Mommy, can I have the whole bag of candy?"
>   mother: "You can have *some* candy."

The only situation I can think of where "do some" doesn't sound awkward is when the word "some" clarifies and emphasizes quantity of a modified noun.

Example #1:

> fan: "When you compete in the Olympics, do you do every event?"
>   athlete: "I do some of the gymnastic events"

Example #2:

> student A: "When the teacher leaves the room, do you do everything you're supposed to?'
>   student B: "I do some of what I'm supposed to."

Sometimes the word "some" even replaces the aforementioned noun:

Example #3:

> Person A: "Do you do drugs?"
>
> Person B: "I do some... But only the legal kind!"

So I would not worry about inserting the word "some" into the sentence, unless you are stressing the amount of fishing.

Comment: When your friend asks what you want to do today, you could also say, "We could do some fishing." But that's because "do some X" means "spend some time engaged in X", and it doesn't mean that "do fishing" is OK.

Comment: @ ferrers of ennui and David. Thank you both. Then can you tell me why this form is that weired? Is saying, " you want to do gardening, or do you know how to do gardening" ok? Then what's difference that gardening case can work, but not the fishing case?

Comment: @JoeKim "do gardening" also presents the same problem. Unfortunately, as a native English speaker, there are some rules I just understand intuitively without always being able to explain "why." I know that "do fishing," "do gardening," and "do hiking," all sound wrong. On the other hand, you can correctly say: "Don't do that!" ; "Did you do your homework?" or "Can you do the dishes?"

Comment: There are some word combinations you might just have to memorize.  Irregular verbs do not have consistent rules for conjugation – some, like “do” you just have to learn contextually. This is part of what can make English confusing for those who didn't grow up speaking it. 
Some guidelines from this [grammar site](http://www.learnenglish.de/grammar/verbtodo.html) might help you:  

Quote: "!Note - As an auxiliary verb 'do' is always followed by the base form of the main verb (infinitive)"

Comment: So if you use “do” as a main verb, such as to say, “do the dishes,” the verb must act on an object (noun), in this case, “dishes.” *However* if you use “do” as an auxiliary verb (along with another action, like “fishing” or “gardening”), you cannot use the same form. The main verb that “do” is helping would have to be in “base form” – such as “Please do come over” or “Do be on time” ("come" and "be" are the main verbs). So you could say “Do you fish in the morning?” or “Don’t fish at night,” but not “do fishing.” I know it can be confusing. Does this help at all? @JoeKim

Comment: Thank you. But before I go on, can I ask you some more: what do you think about these ones: 1. At the lake, we can do some fishing. 2. At the lake, we can do fishing. 3. This afternoon I will do some more fishing. Do you consider them wrong?

Comment: Happy to help. I would only consider #2 wrong. You can use "do" if you also use "some," as David mentioned above. #1 is grammatically correct, but I would consider #3 the best phrasing (in terms of clarity and specificity), because the use of the word "some" serves an unambiguous purpose; it is clear you are specifying the amount of fishing, by combining it with "more." It conveys more detailed information, implying that you already did some fishing earlier, and intend on doing more.

Answer (score 0):

Neither.

In the first case use "[go fishing](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fishing)", (and make it a question)

In the second use "[fish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fish#Etymology_2)" as a verb.

> Do you want to go fishing?
>   Do you know how to fish?

To "go fishing" includes the journey. It also has metephorical uses.

Comment: Thank you. Then can you tell me why this form is that weired? Is saying, " you want to do gardening, or do you know how to do gardening" ok? Then what's difference that gardening case can work, but not the fishing case?